# Accessing a python script in a different folder, using a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can a python script located in `D:\Folder_A\Folder_B\`be used to change variables in another python script located in `D:\Folder_A\Folder_C\`, and then print them out on the console?

NOTE: I'm a beginner in Python, and I'm using v2.7.8.

EDIT: To answer @Rik Verbeek, I created a python file in location A (`D:\Folder_A\Folder_B\`), and another file at location B (`D:\Folder_A\Folder_C\`), with both the folders (`Folder_B` & `Folder_C`) located in `D:\Folder_A\`. In the 2nd .py file, I wrote the following:

`a = 0
 b = 0`

Now I want to change these variables from the 1st .py file to `5` and `10` respectively, and print them to the console. Also, these files are not in the Python libraries, but are instead, located in another folder(`Folder_A`).

To answer @Kasra (and maybe @cdarke), I don't want to import a module, unless it is the only way.

Comment: Be a bit more specific about what you want. Do you want to adjust the script in the folder? Or does your program need to change variables runtime? Also post a bit of code so we know what you created so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Only if you `import` it as a module, not if you run it as a different process (unless you use some form of Inter Process Communication).

Comment: So basically you want to open the file, search for the variables, change the values and safe the file?

Comment: if you want to edit the files or use command `import os`, if not import as a module and make sure it is in your python path

Comment: yse @RikVerbeek, but I also want to print them out on the console of the running script of the 1st .py file. (I know "r+" can do this, but then what will be the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some "global" variables I think is a good idea to have them in a separated module and import that module from each place you need them. This way you only have to do it as **cdarke** has commented.

Comment: so you are saying to make another file, add these variables, and import them wherever I need them?

Comment: Yes, I like this way because you have a module to this explicitly purpose (global variables).